# Use dup() to repeat character X times?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm using this code to print a line width dynamic width:

```
mov cx, width
sep_1:  
    PRINT '-'
loop sep_1
```

For what I understand it should be possible to do something like this, however I haven't managed to make it work:

```
move ax, width
CALL PTHIS
DB 13, 10, ax dup('-'), 0
```

Is it possible to make it any shorter?

Comment: You can't use a runtime expression like a register value as an operand to `dup`.  The count for `dup` needs to be something evaluated at the time the assembler is run.

Comment: then there isn't any way to make it shorter? I really need to shorten it so every line matters.

Comment: There probably is, but not like this. `dup()` is an instruction to the assembler, not to the CPU.

Comment: Also note that line count doesn't really matter, it's the resulting code size that does. Storing a gazillion dashes is not gonna be shorter than the machine code for the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code is the correct way to do this.  Macros are expanded during assembly, you can't use the "dup" macro during runtime, so method 2 is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Fires "-----" into ES:DI

```
 mov ax,"-"
 mov cx,5
 rep stosb
```